# New tag for The Boys

Tags: discussion

I just asked [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/who-is-starlight-supposed-to-be-a-reference-to) about a new show.  However, "The-Boys" is too close to "the-Boy" and it kicked out the tag, so i called it The-Boys-Amazon.  This doesn't seem correct.

What should we tag this with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We should tag it with [the-boys](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-boys), which is the most accurate. It seems the "feature" preventing you from tagging it like that is there to prevent normal users from messing up the tags with unnecessary duplicate tags due to minor typos, similar to the limitation on only changing hyphens.

However, moderators can override that, so I retagged it this way and thereby created the tag, which should from now on be available to normal users, too.